# Scale down a dimension (set max width and height)

Tags: python, image, math, scale, dimension

I'm writing a script to process a bunch of high-res images. Dimensions of these images vary from 1000 to 5000 pixels. To make them ready for web (upload) I need to scale them down.

I'm not interested in the implementation of the scaling down (open image, scale, save, etc.). I'm interested in the calculation of the new scaled down dimensions.

Let's say I have an image with the dimensions 800x2000 pixels and I've set 2400x1200 as the maximum dimensions. The scaled down dimensions of the image should be 480x1200 pixels. Image dimensions cannot overflow the maximum dimensions.

How do I calculate it?

---

While forming the question in my head, I was also experimenting and I came up with the following algorithm:

```
def scale(dim, max_dim):
    new_dim = {"w" : 0, "h" : 0}

    # no change if dim is lower than given max_dim
    if dim["w"] <= max_dim["w"] and dim["h"] <= max_dim["h"]:
        return dim

    ratio = 0

    # detect which side overflows
    if dim["w"] > max_dim["w"]:
        ratio = max_dim["w"] / dim["w"]
    else:
        ratio = max_dim["h"] / dim["h"]

    # scale according to overflowing side
    new_dim["w"] = dim["w"] * ratio
    new_dim["h"] = dim["h"] * ratio

    # now the other side might overflow after scaling
    # check if that's true and scale again
    if new_dim["h"] > max_dim["h"]:
        ratio = max_dim["h"] / dim["h"]
    if new_dim["w"] > max_dim["w"]:
        ratio = max_dim["w"] / dim["w"]

    new_dim["w"] = math.floor(dim["w"] * ratio)
    new_dim["h"] = math.floor(dim["h"] * ratio)

    return new_dim
```

This seems to produce correct results, although I'm not sure if this would be a preferable approach to take. For example, I'm doing two checks; first to detect the overflow, and second, to correct the (possible) second overflow that results from the first scale. I might be doing redundant calculations, so I also need advice on that.

Test cases:

```
max_dim = {"w" : 2400, "h" : 1200}

dim1 = {"w" : 800,  "h" : 1000}
dim2 = {"w" : 800,  "h" : 2000}
dim3 = {"w" : 800,  "h" : 2500}
dim4 = {"w" : 2500, "h" : 800}
dim5 = {"w" : 2500, "h" : 3000}
dim6 = {"w" : 1800, "h" : 1500}
dim7 = {"w" : 2500, "h" : 1000}
dim8 = {"w" : 2500, "h" : 1400}
dim9 = {"w" : 2500, "h" : 2000}

print(scale(dim1, max_dim))
print(scale(dim2, max_dim))
print(scale(dim3, max_dim))
print(scale(dim4, max_dim))
print(scale(dim5, max_dim))
print(scale(dim6, max_dim))
print(scale(dim7, max_dim))
print(scale(dim8, max_dim))
print(scale(dim9, max_dim))
```

Outputs:

```
{'w': 800, 'h': 1000}
{'w': 480, 'h': 1200}
{'w': 384, 'h': 1200}
{'w': 2400, 'h': 768}
{'w': 1000, 'h': 1200}
{'w': 1440, 'h': 1200}
{'w': 2400, 'h': 960}
{'w': 2142, 'h': 1200}
{'w': 1500, 'h': 1200}
```

These outputs are correct. Neither the width nor the height of the entered dimensions overflow the maximum dimensions.

Also, I know Python has built-in methods for image scaling (`resize` and `thumbnail`), but I'll do further modifications (change aspect ratio, set transparent pixels and empty areas to white, etc.), so I need to do the calculation manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to make one comparison (also it is possible to save `Max_W * Hgt` and `Max_H * Wdt` in variables to save onem ore multiplication :))

```
if (Max_W * Hgt < Max_H * Wdt):
    W_Result = Max_W
    H_Result = Hgt * Max_W / Wdt
else:
   W_Result = Wdt * Max_H / Hgt
   H_Result = Max_H
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get the ratio of width and height, based on that you can write a simple if-clause.

```
def resize(width, height):
    pref_width  = 2400
    pref_height = 1200
    pref_ratio = pref_width/pref_height
    ratio = width/height
```

If the image is too wide, the image ratio will be greater than the preferred ratio and we can calculate everything based on the width in order to avoid overflow:

```
    if ratio > pref_ratio:
        return pref_width, height * (pref_width / width)
```

If the image is too large in height, we set the preferred height as the new height and calculate the width accordingly. We don't need to account for the resizable image being the same dimensions, because the formula does not care and gives us the correct answer anyway.

```
    else:
        return width * (pref_height / height), pref_height
```